Anyone come across a concept of vertical spoilers on wings not perpendicular to the flow? As in not following the LE/TE sweep direction?
For reference, I am currently investigating vertically actuated spoilers for gust load alleviation for my master's thesis, and I was wondering, if the concept of non perpendicularly oriented spoilers to the flow direction have ever been tested computationally?
My current thesis plan is to modify a CRM (Common Research Model - A generic transonic transport aircraft model) geometry to include vertically actuated spoilers and simulate them on a FSI (Fluid-Structure-Interaction) framework for various gust loads, however, I was asked by my supervisor to maybe try to come up with a slightly novel idea or an improvement to an existing system, hence this idea came up.
My idea behind it was, If I could orient them in certain angles (basically fixed to the wing at certain angles, not make its angular orientation also a adjustable parameter), I can have a lot more freedom in terms of local loading over the wing, positions and amplitudes of the peak loads generated etc. This would open a lot of control options, which could deal with gust loads, possibly.
Practically I know it may not be very feasible, but I was interested in the idea of doing a FSI Sim to maybe design an optimal layout of a couple spoilers and/or show its effectiveness
I know it would be an extremely complex case, with a lot of variables. I thought of getting the ball rolling with a few simple cases, and varying only a few variables such as angle wrt the flow, height of spoiler deployment, at a fixed position over the wing.
Anyone has come across such use of spoilers? If so, could you direct me to a few references or papers that have studied them?
In the image, Blue lines indicate typical locations for spoiler hinges, The black angled lines is what I want to test

For simplicity reasons and time constraints, I will be ignoring the presence of flaps and control surfaces

Given that on a swept wing the boundary layer moves also outward, setting the spoiler inclined as the rightmost in your picture might actually be beneficial
